# Php recursive function not looping deeper

Tags: php, html, mysql

Am building application whitch will show family tree from database using recrusive function. For start everything work fantastic but my function not looping deeper and loop `child` of their `child`.

This is my example: [image]

On image above looping must also loop `Annie` childs `Steve` and `Rex`.

**Check my code:**

```
<?php
        $categories = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user");
        $data = array();

        // build menu
        function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
            $branch = array();

            foreach ($elements as $element) {

                if ($element['parent'] == $parentId) {
                    $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
                    if ($children) {
                        $element['children'] = $children;
                    }
                    $branch[] = $element;
                }
            }
            return $branch;
        }

        // Child recrusive looping
        function recrusive_child($childs) {
            if(isset($childs)) {
                foreach ($childs as $child) {
                    echo "<li><a href='#'>".$child['username']."</a></li>";
                }
            }
        }

        while ($result = $categories->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $result;
        }

        $tree =  buildTree($data);

        ?>

    <div class="tree">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($tree as $item): ?>
                <?php if($item['parent'] == null): ?>
                    <li><a href=""><?= $item['username'];?></a>
                        <?php if($item['children']): ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php recrusive_child($item['children']); ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thats because your recursive_child isnt really recursive, it never calls itself.

Comment: Right. Let me check and modify and make recrusive child

Comment: Now work good but have problem childs is not shown below child. Now is everything is inline! I must check my css and html to see this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to create recursive category List

```
<?
     function buildTree($parent = 0, $treeArray = '') {

            if (!is_array($treeArray))
            $treeArray = array();

          $sql = "SELECT `cid`, `name`, `parent` FROM `category` WHERE 1 AND `parent` = $parent ORDER BY cid ASC";
          $query = mysql_query($sql);
          if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
             $treeArray[] = "<ul>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
              $treeArray[] = "<li>". $row->name."</li>";
              $treeArray = buildTree($row->cid, $user_tree_array);
            }
            $treeArray[] = "</ul>";
          }
          return $treeArray;
        }
    ?>
 <ul>
    <?php
      $returnedData = buildTree();
      foreach ($returnedData as $returnedD) {
        echo  $returnedD;
      }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a recursive calling of `recrusive_child` (`recursive_child?`)

```
function recrusive_child($childs) {
            if(isset($childs)) {
                foreach ($childs as $child) {
                    echo "<li><a href='#'>".$child['username']."</a>";
                    if ($child['children']){
                        echo "<ul>";
                        recrusive_child($child['children']);
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            }
        }
```